# Why does Dataloader.io not recognize my custom fields?

Tags: fields, production, dataloader.io

I added the fields "External ID" and "Display URL" to my Product object. They are visible for all profiles and not read-only.  They are visible on the product layout, and shown when I do a "New Product."

However, I get the "Select ..." prompt in the Salesforce field column for these fields when doing a Products Import, and my fields aren't available as mappings.  What have I done wrong?

Update: I thought I'd just try doing this again and see if it was something in my workflow, and it must have been.  When I look at my new field (Marketing URL), it is a Product Custom Field with an API name.  But the old field just shows as a Product Field with no API name.  What step did I do incorrectly the first time?

Comment: Can you check with workbench or dataloader.exe

Comment: My first guess would be that the data types are incompatible with the import type, like, for example, if your column contained date values and the External ID field was a numeric field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response from the dataloader.io team:

> DisplayUrl and ExternalId fields from Product2 object were introduced
>   in API version 39, while dataloader.io last release supports until API
>   version 37. This is the reason why you don't see those fields from
>   dataloader.io.